# Store UIImage in iPhone memory through NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsuserdefaults, nsmutabledictionary

I use ASIHTTPRequest library to download picture, I store my picture in a NSMutableDictionnary (key=url, value =UIImage), which permit to me to download one time the picture I need for each of my views. This part works well.

Now I want to store my NSMutableDictionnary named "imagesDownloaded" in iPhone memory to download one time each images for all my application, I do it thanks to this code

```
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[request responseData]];
[imagesDownloaded setValue:img forKey:request.url.description];
userDatas = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDatas setValue:imagesDownloaded forKey:@"Pictures"];
[userDatas synchronize];
```

But it doesn't work, when I do:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [userDatas objectForKey:@"Pictures"]);
```

The value is always "null".

What's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others said, you cannot save an image directly into `NSUserDefaults`.

Although you can save it as an encoded string or something else that can be saved in `NSUserDefaults`, but since the data of an image is much bigger than normal `NSUserDefaults` data, it's bad for performance if you save images into it.

The best way to do so is save your image as a file into iOS's file system, and then you just save the path of the image into `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store an image directly into `NSUserDefaults`. From [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> The `NSUserDefaults` class provides convenience methods for accessing
>   common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A
>   default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections a combination of instances of): `NSData`, `NSString`,
>   `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`. If you want to store any
>   other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an
>   instance of `NSData`.

Since you already have the data for the image (`[request responseData]`), try storing that into the defaults. You can also try putting the `NSData` objects directly into your array rather than the `UIImage` objects, and then store that.

To learn more about using user defaults, check out Apple's [User Defaults Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/UserDefaults.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i)

Answer (score 0):

The object you are storing to the user defaults (and all of it's children) has to be a plist type of object, or in other words, NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary.

I recently did something similar to this, which involves code like this to store the item:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *myEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:appSettings];
[prefs setObject:myEncodedObject forKey:@"appSettings"];
[prefs synchronize];
```

My appSettings class required that I create the encodeWithCoder and initWithCoder methods, but once I did that, I was able to put the class into the user defaults.